# How to sort dates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, sorting

I am currently trying to write a script which sorts dates from an input file and then writes them to a new new output file.
But when running the script the output file is similar to the input file.

Contents of the input file:

```
23.08.2021 
13.08.2031 
13.01.2022
```

Contents of the output file:

```
23.08.2021 
13.08.2031 
13.01.2022
```

This is my code:

```
bands = list()
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file1, open('sample2.txt','w+') as file2:
    for line in file1:
        bands.append(line.strip())
    bands.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(line, "%d.%m.%Y")) 
    for bands in bands:
        file2.write('{} \n'.format(bands))
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Is there something wrong in with my code or am I doing something wrong? If so I would be glad if someone could tell me what I've made wrong and help me fix this problem:)

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Comment: Typo in your sort key: You should use the `date` variable from the lambda not the `line` variable from the previous loop. `bands.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))`

Comment: @Henry Ecker thank you very very much for your fast response:) This fixed it for me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the main issue that you have the wrong argument in the lambda expression: the `line` left from the preceding loop, instead of the argument `date`. The result is that all items get the same key, so they compare as equal, and no sorting is actually done.

Some other small things you could improve:

1. The first loop could be replaced by a list compreshension: `bands = [line.strip() for line in file1]`. You can also use a generator expression instead (but then you need to use `sorted()` instead of `sort()`). Either way is more Pythonic than writing an explicit loop.
2. Writing `for bands in bands`, while technically correct, is *very* bad style (and likely to cause mistakes very similar to the one you made). It would be better to write `for band in bands:` etc. You can also write it all at once using a `join()` (though this may possibly be problematic if the input file can be very large).
3. You seem to add spaces at the end of every line. Did you mean to do that?
4. There is no need to manually close files - this is what the `with` keyword is for (when opening files, anyway). It ensures that the files are closed (even if something you do causes an exception).

For example, you could write this snippet like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file1, open('sample2.txt', 'w+') as file2:
    bands = (line.strip() for line in file1)
    bands = sorted(bands, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
    # alternate, same result
    # bands = [line.strip() for line in file1]
    # bands.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
    file2.write(' \n'.join(bands))
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your time and your help:) this fixed it for me :)

Comment: Sorry for not responding to your questions:/ I didn't mean to add spaces at the end of every line. Thank you very very much for the point outs and suggestions:) Already replaced my snippet with yours:)

Comment: @iLikeCookies: Note that the code in my answer does reproduce the spaces at the end of lines (except for the last one), as well. If you don't want them, remove the space from the `' \n'` literal in `file2.write(' \n'.join(bands))`.